# Does SCSS support inline comments?

Tags: css, sass

Can I keep an inline comment like this in my `.scss` file

```
thead {
    display: table-header-group; // h5bp.com/t
}
```

I don't want this comment in my CSS output.

Comment: That comment won't appear in your CSS output according to the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments). Unless something changed...

Answer (score 110, accepted):

There are two different types of comments to consider in SASS.

1. Single line comments `//` will be removed by the `.scss` pre-processor, and won't appear in your `.css` file.
2. Multiline comments `*/` are valid CSS, and will be preserved between the translation from `.scss` to your `.css` file.

- Except for some compressed modes, unless you start the comment with a `!`.  See http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments.

It sounds like inline comments `//` are what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry i edited my question. I was actually asking for scss comments `//`

Comment: @JitendraVyas - I've updated my answer - `//` comments seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you have your `*/` switched?  multiline comments should be  `/*  your comment here */`

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, you can do it in **SCSS**.

Use inline comment: `//`.

These single-line comments are removed in the CSS output.