# sass comment on the right of a code

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I would like to have the following structure:

```
sass: rule //coment
```

But comments with // seems to be accepted only on new lines.

Is there a way to comment a sass rule in the same line the rule is?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355989/does-sass-support-inline-comments

Comment: True, thanks for point this out. Couldn't find searching stackoverflow

Comment: No problem, i just usually do a google site-specific search for every question b4 i answer it.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative way of writing comments is like this:

```
/* comment text here */
```

Be aware that this type of comment will be preserved in your generated css though, unless you use the compressed option.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that my vim lacks highlight for this comment.

Comment: Documentation backs you up on this but, somehow, I've managed to inherit some .sass file that have these comments . Crazy thing is, sometimes the compiler chokes and sometimes it doesn't! Any insight by any chance?

Comment: @Montagist Sorry, I would just be aimlessly guessing if I tried to suggest anything, you should submit a question of your own with an example or two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  But only on new lines, or after a property:value pair.  Perhaps an obscure bug, but they can break on compile if added after a selector.  This May be fixed in a more recent version of SASS, so if you're having compile problems with comments, check the positioning as stated below (or update your version).

i.e.

```
// This works
.myclass
    width: 30px //comment

// This breaks for some on compile
.myclass //comment
    width: 30px

// This style is sass only and won't be compiled/output in the final css file
/* this style will be seen in final css file as a normal css comment */
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually right now nothing breaks compiling any longer. Test yourself. I have answered my own question.

Comment: Ok great!  Maybe it's a recent update (answer updated). We were testing this yesterday, and noticed that it compiles fine for some people in our office, and breaks for others (but only if there is a comment after a selector).  It's very odd behavior.