# SASS won't compile WordPress stylesheet because of comments

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, comments

I am using Koala to auto-compile style.sass and apparently it's not liking the required multiline comments at the beginning of the file (ie: /* Theme Name:...*/).

I get an error every time I try to compile it:

WARNING on line 2 of style.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
WARNING on line 3 of style.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
WARNING on line 5 of style.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...nsive, modern, ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "and elegant wed..."
        on line 6 of style.sass

Should I just compile it and add the multiline comments to the compressed style.css afterwards? That would be a headache.

It seems that because the comments have a ":" it thinks it's a css property.

EDIT, here's the code:

```
/*
Theme Name: ...
Theme URI: ...
Author: ...
Author URI: ...
Description: A responsive, modern, and elegant wedding theme.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: ...
*/


// Micro Clearfix //

.cf:before,
.cf:after 
    content: " " // 1
    display: table // 2

.cf:after
    clear: both

// For IE 6/7 only. Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
.cf
    *zoom: 1


// Defaults //

html,
body
    font-size: 100%
    width: 100%


// SASS Variables //

$fuchsia: #fe4365
$pink: #fc9d9a
$salmon: #f9cdad
$olive: #c8c8a9
$teal: #83af9b
```

Comment: can you show us the style sheet associated with the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compress your CSS, then you need to add the exclamation point (!). However, if you are not trying to, then any type of commenting style should suit you. An example of the commenting that is acceptable is below. More information on comments can be found on this [page](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html#comments) and [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355989/does-sass-support-inline-comments) is useful as well.

```
/* This comment is
 * several lines long.
 * since it uses the CSS comment syntax,
 * it will appear in the CSS output. */

/*! This comment is
 * several lines long.
 * since it uses the CSS comment syntax,
 * it will appear in the CSS output. */

// Does not appear in output.
```

Comment: I am compressing. Tried the exclamation as mentioned in the comment above. I also tried putting the asterisk on each line.

Comment: Never mind, tried it EXACTLY as you formatted it with the exclamation and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a ! before the comments you wish to keep:

```
/*!
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
*/
```