# Comment out code in SASS compiler

Tags: sass

I have commented out SASS code:

```
/*
 * @for $i from 1 through 5 {
 *        .class-#{$i} {
 *             color: #000;
 *        }
 *   }
*/
```

but I still receive information like this:

```
Undefined variable: "$i".
```

Try to put the code above to the sassmeister.com and you will receive the same info about undefined variable or try to compile (in SASS) the above code to receive the same info.

**Is it correctly commented out?**

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, according to this post : [Does SCSS support inline comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355989/does-sass-support-inline-comments)

- `//` is "real" Sass comment, it means that the comment won't be
  processed.
- `/*` is CSS comment, which means that the comment will be processed by Sass and appear in the compiled CSS (as a CSS comment).