# wrong auto comments for scss in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue with the auto comments in my .scss files. By auto comments I mean 'CTRL + /' to comment out the selected code. When I'm in my scss file and I do this, it adds the JS comments '//'. So the output looks like this:

```
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  // overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When it should be:

```
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
```

If I rename the .scss file to .css then the auto comments work correctly. I'm guessing this has to do with a setting inside of VSCode, either user or workspace setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is working as expected, as [SCSS supports both ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355989/does-scss-support-inline-comments/13356051) to comment, and I do not think there are any settings in Visual Studio Code you can change to change how the comment style works.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is "Toggle Line Comment", which is the `//` way.  If you want to comment using the multi-line comment format, you can instead highlight what it is you want to comment, and perform <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

[image: shift alt a way]

However, there is another way to change how the Line Comments work:

- Find where Visual Studio Code is installed on your system, and go to resources → app → extensions → scss
- In the scss folder should be a ["language-configurations.json"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) file.  Open it.
- Change the `lineComment` property to be either a blank string, or delete it outright.

```json
"lineComment": ""
```

- Save the file, and restart Visual Studio Code.  Now when you perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, it should comment using the style you prefer.

Comment: I don't think `lineComment` in a language-configuration file can take an array.

Comment: It says `Incorrect type. Expected "string".` when I try it.

Comment: The reason it worked for you I think is because you "borked" the `lineComment` value and so it fell back to using the unchanged `blockComment` value for line comments.  It works for me if I just delete the `lineComment` key/value altogether.  It also works if you just set `lineComment":""` the empty string.

Comment: @Mark I actually edited the file using notepad++ so I didn't see the errors, but... that works too then I suppose?  I guess it's more of a hack than a fix.

Comment: Yes, a little lucky in that it graciously uses the `blockComment` value and that the `blockComment` value is what the OP wanted for line comments.  I'll add an answer about an alternative that also deals with the file overwriting issue.  Upvoting yours.

Comment: @Mark thanks! And good find. I updated my post as well.

Comment: It seems that VScode changed it back, maybe after an update the file got corrected? I had to go back in and change it again.

Comment: @RobbieC yes, sometimes updates can overwrite these files, as explained in Mark's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the comments to @Timothy's answer.  I have previously written an extension to deal with these issues, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax), that allows you to easily change things like line or block comments for many languages.

But setting `lineComment` to the OP's desired `["/*","*/"]` did not work.  In looking at the scss language configuration file, an array of values is not allowed for line comment values.  But it works to delete the lineComment key or setting it to the empty string `""`.

However, although probably rare, any language configuration file can be overwritten whenever vscode updates and you would have to go back and change the file again.  Hence the extension.

With this setting:

```
"custom-language-properties": {
  "scss.comments.lineComment": ""
}
```

this accomplishes the same thing as editing the underlying language-configuration file.  And fortunately, at least in this case, apparently vscode will apply the `blockComment` value when the `lineComment` value is missing or inappropriate.  And fortunately that `blockCcomment` style is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That is valid comment syntax for SCSS, and it's probably the correct default.

Single-line comments (which start with `//`) are always removed from the compiled output, which is usually what you want.

Multi-line comments (`/* comment */`) are only removed in `compressed` mode.

Source: [Sass: Comments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/comments#in-scss)